# How can i set timer to 1 sec. while counting?

Tags: delphi

Here is code in Timer. I want when i click on button to set timer to 0sec, timer to count from 0sec.

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inc(a);
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(a);
  if a >= 61 then
    ShowMessage('Time is up!');
end;
```

Comment: Please ask a question

Comment: What is `a` to begin with?

Answer (score 3):

In your button click event enable the timer and set your count variable a to 0:

```
Timer1.Enabled := true;
a := 0;
```

Also, when your timer eventually reaches 61 (or whatever stopping point), you will probably want to disable the timer.

Answer (score 2):

The unit for the timer interval is milliseconds. If you want the timer to trigger every second you must set the interval to 1000.

BTW, you should consider using a different approach than calling ShowMessage inside the timer event.

Comment: ... or at least disable timer before using modal dialog.